# Find accommodations in New York

Tags: usa, accommodation

I'm moving to New York in September as I won the green card lottery last year. I need to find a place to stay. I've searched some rental websites but was unable to find something good for a reasonable price ($650 cmp).

Could you share some tips I perhaps haven't considered to find nice, peaceful place to live in New York? I can't pay more than mentioned above, because it will take some time to find a job.

Also if you can give me advice which part of the city is better? I mean not too expensive, finding jobs easily, etc....

Comment: Why New York? It is a very expensive area.

Comment: Thanks patricia, so could you suggest me somewhere else?

Comment: Indeed I don't matter much, where I go at first it's important to find some calm place and get job.

Comment: NY because most people telling me it's easy to get a job there

Comment: Given you're a programmer: North Carolina(RTP), Texas(Dallas, Austin), Washington(Seattle), Oregon, Chicago, etc.  If you have the skills it's easy to get a job almost everywhere.  The problem is that pay in most areas doesn't match NYC because the cost of living is lower.

Comment: I would suggest starting to look for a job rather than looking for a place first.

Comment: @Karlson thanks for the suggestion, you are right. Would suggest some good agency or something like that who could help me in that? I like chicago or Oregon, maybe carolina too

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili Post your resume on Monster, Dice, HotJobs, http://stackoverflow.com/jobs, recruiters will find you if you're worth finding.

Comment: Note: OP has a hard deadline to enter the US, so he may not be able to get a job before he has to move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going about it backwards.  You need to find a place to work and then look for a place to live.

You could probably start by looking at the job sites like [Monster](http://www.monster.com), [Hotjobs](http://www.hotjobs.com), [Stackoverflow Jobs](http://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs), or [Dice](http://www.dice.com) to see where positions that you might be interested in are and then start looking for a place to live.

There are sites like [Apartments.com](http://www.apartments.com), [Rent.com](http://www.rent.com), or [Zillow](http://www.zillow.com) that could get you started in looking for a place to live.

Now as far as NY is concerned there are very few places that would meet your price range criteria but if you want to find a place like that you are better off having someone local who can look for a place for you because not everything would be listed online.

Comment: You should look at job ads and apartment ads together. In the USA the same salary can mean a dramatically different standard of living depending on location.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan You should start looking for a job first.  Once the job is found you can get recommendations for a place to live from future coworkers.

Comment: I looked, several times, at moving from San Diego to the San Francisco area. I could have got a substantially larger salary, but a reduced standard of living because of the housing cost difference. You may have a general idea which areas are expensive - the OP may not.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan That's what [sites like this](http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/comparison.jsp) are for.  And besides OP is not moving from one place in the US to another.  The expectations are completely different.

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is [Craig's List](https://newyork.craigslist.org/) and look for a roommate. The [roommate page is here,](https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/roo) but there are other options on this website also.

While Craig's List is a decent place to find a place to live in New York - and other cities - beware of scams. Do a reasonable amount of research about the place, and don't wire money; wait until you meet the other flatmates before you contribute even one cent.